# Finding specific items in an Shared Folder/Network Drive with limited knowledge

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a project with some people on campus that uses binaries, and the professor overseeing our project has asked that we use git and it pretty set on its use. One of the big problems we are having are these constant questions flooding our group chats regarding who is working on which file, and if the file each of us needs to edit is free.

In my spare time I've been doing some gui practice, and thought a nice practical application would be a simple tkinter gui that queries and/or writes to some discreet text file with a dynamic list of all the files currently being edited on a mapped share drive that we all have. I've been able to verify most of the program, but am running into a theoretical issue:

After talking with some members of my group I've learned that each of us have mapped the shared folder to a different drive letter on our PC's, and we have one member who mapped their drive letter to one folder directory above where other members mapped.

---

TLDR:

I need a way to find a common file in python via a network drive/shared folder whilst:

1. Not being entirely sure of the drive letter
2. Or...  where in the directory tree the user mapped their drive letter

And the goal is to do this via python for my tkinter GUI.

---

P.S. I would prefer to not hard code this. I see this as an opportunity to maybe learn how to develop tools during potential internships and doing such would not really help me on that front.

Comment: A major advantage of git as a version control system is that, with branching and merging, several people can be working on the same file at once, and combine the results later.  Perhaps you should look at how you are using git to avoid the need for this 'locking' mechanism?

Comment: I would love to just use git, but the binaries are impossible to do any sort of merging or diffing to. I know LFS is a thing, but the stash server we are using apparently isn't set up for the LFS uppdate that allows binary locking. It doesn't seem to be a matter of using git correctly, it is that we need to use it despite the project type being a bad fit.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to simply ask each *user* where they've located the shared folder:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import libraries for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    import tkinter.filedialog as tkfd
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkFileDialog as tkfd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    shared_folder = tkfd.askdirectory()

    root.mainloop()
```